# Como hacer una Consulta de UNION en SYMFONY

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Como podría hacer la siguiente consulta en Symfony

```
SELECT *
FROM ((
SELECT SUM(o0_.qty) AS sclr_0, o0_.price AS price_1, i1_.numero AS numero_2, i1_.nombre AS nombre_3, i1_.um AS um_4, i1_.id AS id_5
FROM ofer_producto o0_
INNER JOIN inv_producto i1_ ON (i1_.id = o0_.producto_id)
INNER JOIN ofer_oobra o2_ ON (o2_.id = o0_.oo_id)
INNER JOIN ofer_oferta o3_ ON (o2_.ofert_id = o3_.id)
WHERE o3_.id = 2
GROUP BY o0_.price, i1_.numero, i1_.nombre, i1_.um, i1_.id) UNION (
SELECT SUM(f0_.cant) AS sclr_0, f0_.price AS price_1, i1_.numero AS numero_2, i1_.nombre AS nombre_3, i1_.um AS um_4, i1_.id AS id_5
FROM fab_mate f0_
INNER JOIN inv_producto i1_ ON (i1_.id = f0_.producto_id)
INNER JOIN fab_produc f2_ ON (f2_.id = f0_.fab_id)
INNER JOIN ofer_fabricacion o3_ ON (f2_.id = o3_.fab_id)
INNER JOIN ofer_oobra o4_ ON (o4_.id = o3_.oo_id)
INNER JOIN ofer_oferta o5_ ON (o4_.ofert_id = o5_.id)
WHERE o5_.id = 2
GROUP BY f2_.code, f2_.name, f0_.price, i1_.numero, i1_.nombre, i1_.um)) AS tt
```

Comment: Hola Aslee, por favor desarrolla lo que quieres hacer, la bola de cristal se perdio XD.

Comment: Viendo el query puedes hacer los dos subquerys por separado y mergear los resultados.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` no está soportado por DQL actualmente.

No obstante, puedes usar SQL nativo y mapeo de resultset, como se indica aquí: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comenta el compañero [Muriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/5813/muriano), en DQL no tienes soporte para el `UNION`.

Date cuenta que Doctrine, se compone de varios subproyectos:

- Capa de abstracción de base de datos, o [DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html).
- Capa de mapeo relacional de objetos, u [ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).

Tiene más subproyectos y componentes, pero para lo que tratamos ahora mismo, estos son los que nos interesan.

Dentro del ORM, tienes varios métodos para realizar consultas a la base de datos:

- [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)
- [QueryBuilder API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) (que construye DQL, ojo)
- [SQL Nativo](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Así mismo, y gracias a los mecanismos de Hidratación, puedes seguir trabajando con objetos exactamente igual; aquí puedes verlo:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes

Te recomiendo que revises la documentación de Doctrine, que no se trata demasiado en la documentación oficial de Symfony (con buen criterio, ya que es un proyecto diferente, y no tienes por que usar Doctrine como ORM); es un poco farragosa, pero te ayudará muchísimo a entender qué estás haciendo exactamente cuando utilizas Doctrine, cuando haces uso del API del QueryBuilder, cuando usas DQL, etc.; además de que ves que los supuestos cuellos de botella de velocidad que puede originar un ORM, pueden ser solventados perfectamente, sabiendo como.

Espero te sea de ayuda, un saludo.